# React Firebase, Await data before do code

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I get this error with a function in react. How can I make sure the I received the data before i use .push?

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'push' of null

```
 const joinTheLobby = () => {
    if(lobbyKey != ''){
        // Add Player to DB Lobby.
        const db = firebase.database().ref(`Lobby/${lobbyKey}/players`);
        let allPlayers = [];
        let pushPlayers = [];
        let newPlayer = {'userName': userName};

        db.on('value', async (snapshot) => {
            allPlayers = await snapshot.val();

            allPlayers.push(newPlayer);

            allPlayers.map(({userName}) => {
                pushPlayers.push(userName);
            });
        });
```

This is how I fire the function. Also, Will this function run immediately after state updates?

```
                <button onClick={joinTheLobby}>Join</button>
```

Comment: I suggest reading the error message carefully.  Why are you expecting the returned `null` to have a method called push()?  null doesn't have any methods or properties.  Are you sure you meant to overwrite the initial value of the variable `allPlayers`?  Seems like you should check for null first before doing anything.

Comment: It works now that I changed the my 'let allPlayers = []' to 'var allPlayers = []'. Now I have a simple array with players ['player1','player2' etc..] - How can I update the state with this array? At the moment I'm using this: setPlayers(arr => [...arr, pushPlayers]); but I want to make sure that the new array will completely replace the old array. Thanks

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your database structure so we could see properties present in each player node?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this code, `snapshot.val()` is most likely returning `null`.

`null` is a valid thing for it to return according to the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val

So, most likely this `Lobby/${lobbyKey}/players` does not exist in Firebase.

Comment: It works now that I changed the my 'let allPlayers = []' to 'var allPlayers = []'. Now I have a simple array with players ['player1','player2' etc..] - How can I update the state with this array? At the moment I'm using this: setPlayers(arr => [...arr, pushPlayers]); but I want to make sure that the new array will completely replace the old array. Thanks

Comment: Does it really break when you switch back to `let allPlayers`? About the rest, what you are trying to do did not make sense to me to be honest.

Comment: I have an array1 = ['player13','player20']. I also have state array = ['player1','player2']. How can I set the state array to be array1 ?

Comment: and yes it works fine in the database with var

Comment: did you try `setState(array1)`?